# HTML parsing-what kind of thread should i use?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, html-parsing, backgroundworker

I have a method which doing parsing to a html document but it takes a long of time and the UI freezes. So i want to use a thread but i am confused. There are many kinds of threads, like background workers, dispatchers etc. What type should i use?  Also, in my method i pass a parameter. How can pass one parameter if i use a thread?

Comment: I often use Actions, but a side question is what kind of parameters are we talking about?

Comment: I pass a string parameter with the url of html document...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code using background worker:

```
// I usually disable controls (buttons, etc.)
// so user is prevented to perform other
// actions
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
     // Get the parameter
     var param = e.Argument as <your expected object>
     // Perform parsing
}
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s1, e1) =>
{
     System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
             // enable you controls here
        }));
}
worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameter);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I put my code in dowork, but it doesn't look likes to work. I have a listview in dowork and it doesn't fill.

Comment: i have a method where i parse a html and i create dynamically a listview with the content which i got from the html. In RunWorkerCompleted the //enable you controls here what means? can i update  my ui controls in there? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using backgroundworkers anymore since WPF. I heard It was created for WinForms and should be avoided in WPF, however I could be mistaken.
Since you are passing a string as a parameter (and not some ui control) there should be no problem accessing another thread like this:

```
private void DoStuff(string documentName)
{
    Action a = () => 
    {
        var result = ParseFile(documentName);
        Action b = () => 
        {
            TextBox1.Text = result;
        };
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(b);
    };
    a.BeginInvoke(callback => 
    {
        a.EndInvoke(callback);
    }, null);
}
```

Note: Do not put the delegates inside a loop, rather put a loop inside the delegate.